# Is it OK to use "after a moment," "not long after," and "before long" interchangeably?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I write stories, and I often find myself writing "after a moment," in too many parts.

> On their table was a smoked salmon, grilled meat,
>   a plate of sushi, mussels, some salad, a basket with bread, and two
>   bottles of Italian wine. The group seemed to be in some kind of
>   celebration.
>
> **After a moment,** a girl approached the table, holding a huge birthday cake with twenty candles on it.

So in this case I wanted to change **after a moment** for **not long after.** Would the meaning be pretty much the same? How about **before long**?

Comment: A bit later... Some time passed and... After a while...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use them interchangeably.

I would, however, question whether you even need to indicate the passing of time.

Would not:

> **At their table** was a smoked salmon, grilled meat, a plate of sushi, mussels, some salad, a basket with bread, and two bottles of Italian wine. The group seemed to be **enjoying** some kind of celebration.
>
> A girl approached the table, holding a huge birthday cake with twenty candles on it.

be equally good, and somewhat more concise? The passing of a short but negligible amount of time is implied, and does not really need to be stated.

It is a matter of taste, but usually 'less is more'.

Answer (score 2):

Compare these examples.

"A young man walked to the edge of the cliff. After a moment, he dived into the water."

"A young man walked to the edge of the cliff. Not long after, he dived into the water."

The first has a sense of immediacy. Nothing happened between the two sentences.

The second one makes it sound like he did some other stuff before he took the dive. (E.g. maybe he undressed or something.) I think "before long" is even less immediate than the other two. For example:

"A young man walked to the edge of the cliff. After a moment, he dived into the water. Not long after, another youth dived after him. Before long, a line formed."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "After a moment, you can write either : Within a moment or After a short time..

Before long will change its meaning completely.. Not long after seems to be incomplete because you need to specify after what..

As in the sentence , it is mentioned : After a moment...

Answer (score 0):

I detest almost any use of "moment" phrases. Kill them if at all possible. Worst: "He paused for a long moment...: No, "He paused." Period. Stephen King himself is a horrible offender.

Comment: Hello, Jean. One person's opinion is usually (as here) off-topic on ELU, and this involves most questions about style rather than acceptability on grounds of grammaticality / idiomaticity / clarity. It's basically the question that is out of place here; I've close-voted on 'primarily opinion-based answers will result' grounds.